# RegEx for occurrence of a constant followed by any string up to a whitespace or end of string

Tags: regex, lua, coronasdk

I'm looking for a RegEx for occurrence of "data/" followed by any string up to a whitespace or end of string?

```
2 * data/color * 8 - finds "data/color"
2 * data/coloring * 8 / 34 - finds "data/coloring"
color plus 22 data/credit -- finds "data/credit"
```

Some example tried;

```
data/[^\S]+\s
data/[^\S]+(\s|^)
data/\w+\s
data/\w+(\s|^)
```

Thanks for the help found solution in LUA (corona SDK);

```
data\/[^\t ]+
```

I had to be specific for some reason can't use "\s";

```
data\/[^\s]+  , fails
```

Comment: Your efforts so far ? `Thanks tried all sorts of combos and can't crack it.` can you post your tried combos in question ?

Comment: You can use `data\/[^ ]+`  [try demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZqhwv/1/)

Comment: `[^\S]` negates the non whitespace char which might be written as `\s` You could use `data/\S+` instead [demo](https://regex101.com/r/X5Iey4/1)

Comment: data/\S+ doesn't work in the corona SDK, data\/[^ ]+ does but only for spaces so used data\/[^\t ]+ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any thing until a space would look like this: `data\/[^\s]+`

data + / (escaped /) + [^\s]+ (anything but a space 1 or more times)

https://regexr.com/4c8cr

Comment: Tried this originally, for some reason in LUA it does not work, I had to use: data\/[^\t ]+ and be specific on the white spaces